# sending emails on codeigniter failed without error

Tags: codeigniter

in the last hours, i try to understand, why my scripts not sending an email.

at the end of generate the emailcontent i send it with this code

```
if ($this->email->send()) 
{
            //all is fine
}
else
{ 
//we have a problem 
}
```

Everytime all the thinks seems ok, emailadresses, content etc. in no case the send() command will returned failed.

What can it caused or how i can get closer to the problem?

In my serverlogfiles i also cannot see somethink about that.

Hope somebody has a idear...

Is there a way to output all current email-settings?

Comment: show_error($this->email->print_debugger()); debug using this

Comment: if i try this i get "An Error Was Encountered" with white page, no more info

Comment: May be you mail configuration wrong

Comment: how i can output the complete configuartion short before sending the mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Its works for me via **localhost**

```
function sendMail()
{
    $config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
  'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

        $message = '';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
      $this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');// change it to yours
      $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
      $this->email->message($message);
      if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email sent.';
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
```

Comment: ok, if i try this, i recieve the email - what can be the reason that the other email wont send instead there is no error-message?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying other emails? what do you mean by that? and also won't send instead and not sending the email. Do not get you please clear your question

Comment: with -other- i mean the email wich i send in my code, there is no error but no email comes in...

Comment: what is your email address would you please provide that? and also which server your useing?

Comment: how i can output the complete configuartion short before sending the mail?